# Do browsers cache Audio when I use the same audio file in the same component reused in multiple parts of the app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

I have the following Button component that's used in many parts in my React App.

```
import React from 'react';
import clickSound from "./clickSound.wav";

function Button()
{
    const audio = new Audio( clickSound );

    const onClick = () =>
    {
        audio.play()
        // other onClick actions
    }

    return (

        <button className="Button" onClick={ onClick }>
            Play 
        </button>

    )
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a valid question but I want to know if the component above creates a new instance of the Audio in every new use of the component; or is there a caching system that prevents new instance initialization of the same Audio?

What about if I use the same sound file in a different component as follows?

```
import React from 'react';
import clickSound from "./Button/clickSound.wav";

function Button2()
{
    const audio = new Audio( clickSound );

    const onClick = () =>
    {
        audio.play()
        // other onClick actions
    }

    return (

        <button className="Button2" onClick={ onClick } >
            Play
        </button>

    )
}
```

Comment: afaik, `new Audio()` creates a new instance (and not just for the component but on each new render with your current code), but the file itself is in the browser's cache and won't exist multiple times.

Comment: Thank you. Is that the best implementation or should I create a mechanism by which I can have it create only one instance?

Comment: The instance itself will barely use any RAM, so I wouldn't worry about it. If you do want to use only a single instance, create a separate module and export a `playClick` function from it.

Comment: Good suggestion, thank you!